# mongodb php-driver : php startup error

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-15.10

I installed mongodb php-driver as per the guideline shown here:
 
    https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver

But when I run `#php` command its showing following error :

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
'/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/mongodb.so' - 
/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/mongodb.so: symbol 
CRYPTO_get_locking_callback, version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file 
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 with link time reference in Unknown on line 0
```

I am using :

```
Lampp Stack
PHP : 7.0.0 
OS: Ubuntu 15.10
Pear: 1.10.1
```

Please suggest any solution if you have. Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have SSL library enabled/installed correctly on your system. Most likely, I am thinking you don't have the `libssl-dev` package installed.

You should install this with `apt-get install libssl-dev libsasl2-dev`, and then reinstall the `mongodb` extension with `pecl uninstall mongodb && pecl install mongodb`.